# Not able to select JSON index when using ngResource in factory

Tags: javascript, angularjs, json, ngresource, angularjs-factory

`ngResource` in `factory` works fine but unfortunately the result able to select `JSON` index. At the same time it is possible to bind the same `$scope.resultItems` variable

Console log appear like this

[image]

Not working from ngResource http://codepen.io/anon/pen/dMbRXx

Working fine from variable http://codepen.io/anon/pen/ONLgNX

```js
var app = angular.module('app', ['ngResource']);
app.controller('myCtrl', function($scope, categoryFilter) {
  $scope.resultItems = categoryFilter.query();
  $scope.resultIndex = $scope.resultItems[0];
  $scope.resultIndexItem = $scope.resultItems[0].status;
});
app.factory('categoryFilter', function($resource) {
  return $resource("https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=NY", {}, {
    query: {
      method: "GET"
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.3.14/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular-resource/1.5.0/angular-resource.min.js"></script>

<div class="container" ng-app="app" ng-controller="myCtrl">
  <div class="col-xs-12">
    <h3>ngResource result</h3>
    <pre>{{resultItems | json }}</pre>
    <hr />
    <pre>{{resultIndex | json }}</pre>
    <hr />
    <pre>{{resultIndexItem | json}}</pre>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Each resource in fact is a ajax request that means it is asynchronous, So you have to use callbacks to `query` function. Then your code looks like this

```
var app = angular.module('app', ['ngResource']);
app.controller('myCtrl', function($scope, categoryFilter) {
  categoryFilter.query(function(results){
    $scope.resultItems  = results;
    $scope.resultItems.results[0];
$scope.resultIndexItem = $scope.resultItems.status;
  });    
});
app.factory('categoryFilter', function($resource) {
  return $resource("https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=NY", {}, {
    query: {
      method: "GET"
    }
  });
});
```

[link](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/PNYKEa)

**Update**

Sorry If I miss read you question, All items in json within `{}` will be an object can be accessed using `.`, For example in json  `results` and `status` is object and items represented in `[]` is an array and they can be accessed using index.

From [json](http://json.org)
[image]
[image]

Comment: The question is that to select json index for example `$scope.resultItems[0]` or `$scope.resultItems[0].status`